# Is Oracle committed to JavaFX?

Tags: java, desktop-application, javafx

I've been researching about building desktop application with JavaFX framework. Does anyone have any good or bad experience that can tell us?

Is Oracle committed to JavaFX?

Comment: Updated JavaFX roadmap http://javafx.com/roadmap/ on oct 13 2011 At JavaOne 2010, Oracle laid out a long-term roadmap for JavaFX to make it a premier rich client platform. JavaFX 2.0 is a significant milestone towards fulfilling this vision. The following section provides a roadmap of upcoming features in the JavaFX platform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oracle have numerous times stated their commitment to JavaFX. The real problem however is that the developers are mostly unimpressed with JavaFX and its adoption so far is very little. Many analysts think that JavaFX came too late and was practically stillborn. If Oracle don't devise quickly a way to make money out of it I can only assume their commitment to the technology will fade away...

Answer (score 1):

Check out these URLs to determine for yourself if Oracle is committed to JavaFX or not.

http://java.com/roadtrip.

http://www.oraclemagazine-digital.com/oraclemagazine/20100708?sub_id=qRRwFN1nldhW&folio=48#pg51

http://www.oracle.com/us/javaonedevelop/063296.html#javafx

Comment: The oraclemagazine-digital.com link gives me an error, because I'm not an authorized subscriber. What's the gist of the article?

Comment: Funny, it no longer works for me either. 
The gist of the article talks about the current Java road trip. On the road trip they are talking about current happenings with Java and JavaFX. This culminates with JavaONE in San Francisco in Sept.

Comment: On a side note, ScalaFX is a thing of beauty (www.scalafx.org).  From working with JavaFX for about a year, the observable properties and observable lists are nice.  Native packaging for various platforms is a plus.